# Passing data from Tableview to Viewcontroller using segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to pass data from my **table cell** to next **ViewController**.

My code is as following:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let caseid = caseData[indexPath.row]["caseid"] as? String
    print(caseid!)
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
        if (segue.identifier == "Viewmore") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewData
            vc.case_id = (caseData[indexPath.row]["caseid"] as? String)!
            print(vc.case_id)
        }
    }
}
```

But I cannot get data in **if Condition**.`vc.case_id` print Nothing.

Comment: Are you creating prepareForSegue inside didSelectRowAt ? Oh my :D

Comment: Did you check  prepareForSegue is calling or not ? , I don't think it will . Just  remove nested function there `prepareForSegue` is separate method while didSelect is separate method

Comment: I have tried as a separate method but there is no change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)